# autofs usb configuration

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm trying to configure

```
/etc/autofs/auto.misc
```

to automount external CDs and USB drives. It worked fine until I reinserted a USB drive; it got renamed from `sdb` to `sdc`.

How can I anticipate such changes in my configuration file?

```
# This is an automounter map and it has the following format 
# key [ -mount-options-separated-by-comma ] location
# Details may be found in the autofs(5) manpage

cdrom -fstype=iso9660,ro,nodev,nosuid :/dev/cdrom
floppy -fstype=auto,async,nodev,nosuid,umask=000 :/dev/fl
usbstick1 -fstype=auto,async,nodev,nosuid,umask=000 :/dev/sda1
usbstick2 -fstype=auto,async,nodev,nosuid,umask=000 :/dev/sdb1
```